# trouble for read raster in R

Tags: r, ubuntu, rgdal

I'm in trouble for read a raster layer in R studio software. When I run the command line for read a raster the software returns me the message:

NOTE: rgdal::checkCRSArgs: no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files

I use OS Ubuntu 15

Somebody can help to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to a bad version of PROJ.4 that should go away if you update it. 
Did you do a search on "no proj_defs.dat in PROJ.4 shared files" ?
You would find helpful answers, for example [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-geo/2015-September/023396.html)

Comment: Thank, From what I understand, the problem is the absence of a "proj_def.dat" in a specific directory. I installed the recent version of libproj 4.9.1-2, and the problem remains. How can I add manually the proj_def.dat?

Comment: Find PROJ.4 4.9.2